# Laravel redirect inside of Trait with input and variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, session-variables, traits

I know, I can redirect back from traits with send() method but code only redirect back without session.

```
if ($address_validation->isAmbiguous()) {
    $suggestedAddresses = $address_validation->getCandidateAddressList();
    redirect()->back()->with('suggestedAddresses', $suggestedAddresses)->withInput($request->all())->send();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return it from trait in your controller, don't use send() method if you want to redirect back with session.

**// In your trait**

```
return redirect()->back();
```

**then in your controller,**

```
$response = mytraitFunction();
if ($response is instanceof RedirectResponse)
return $response->with('success', $response['message'])->withInput($request->all());
```

Don't forget to use: **use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;**